# Why does this case-sensitive CMake condition on the CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR variable fail?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to build a project I found on GitHub and it fails because apparently CMake did not detect a supported architecture:

```
cmake_minimum_required(3.1)
project(myproject LANGUAGES CXX C)


# Architecture string.
set(ARCH "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}" CACHE STRING "Override CPU architecture")
string(REGEX REPLACE "amd64" "x86_64" KERNEL_ARCH "${ARCH}")


if("${KERNEL_ARCH}" STREQUAL "x86_64")
  set(ARCH "x64")
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Unsupported ARCH: ${KERNEL_ARCH}")
endif()
```

This always fails with the error:

> Unsupported ARCH: AMD64

I'm on Windows and my architecture is x86_64. I have an Intel i7.

Comment: So what is the output?

Comment: @KamilCuk Unsupported ARCH: AMD64

Comment: `Why does CMake condition fail?` Because `AMD64` does not match `x86_64`. I do not understand.

Comment: OK I understand now why it's failing. But aren't AMD64 and x86_64 the same thing? Are Intel CPUs supposed to be detected as AMD64 so that x86_64 always fails? This CMake script would fail on most computers right?

Comment: `aren't AMD64 and x86_64 the same thing?` Well, they are different _strings_. Note that `string(REGEX REPLACE "amd64"` is trying to replace `amd64` not `AMD64`, which might be the error.

Comment: [They say](https://superuser.com/questions/305901/possible-values-of-processor-architecture) that possible values of `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` environment variable on Windows doesn't include `x86_64`. Exactly that variable is read by CMake when determine the system architecture on Windows: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.html.

Comment: `STREQUAL` compares the equality of strings. not the equality of architecture names.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the project didn't account for the possibility of different casing. Their regex expression for [`string(REGEX REPLACE)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-replace) is `amd64`, which doesn't match your `AMD64`.

See docs for [`CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.html):

> When not cross-compiling, this variable has the same value as the [`CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.html#variable:CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR) variable.

And docs for [`CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` on Windows platforms](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.html#windows-platforms), which states:

> On Windows, this variable is set to the value of the environment variable `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`.

Even weirder to me (since I'm not familiar with this environment variable or the project you are having problems with), https://superuser.com/q/305901/1749748 (which refers to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details) does not list the lowercase version as a possible value of the environment variable. Perhaps the lowercase version is normal for other platforms (such as Unix ones (see [the related CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.html#unix-platforms))) and the project maintainer never tested on Windows platforms. I'd suggest you raise an issue ticket to them to get this case handled.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it.